# Can't install 19.04 on UEFI laptop (GRUB install error)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

This is my situation:

I have a laptop with UEFI, Secure Boot can't be turned off at all. 
There are 2 ssd drives: the first one with Windows 10 and the second used to be a storage drive in NTFS.

I've shrinked the partition of the second drive from Win10 to make room for Ubuntu. So there was unlocated space at the end of the drive.

I've phisically removed the Win10 ssd drive from the laptop because I don't want to risk touching it at all.

I've launched Ubuntu 19.04 from a USB pen (created with Rufus). I had to use nouveau.modeset=0 at boot otherwise Ubuntu would freeze (nvidia 1070 and intel integrated gpu).

I've created in the free space from Ubuntu 3 partitions: an EFi of 1 GB, a root and a home partition in extfs4.

The installation starts but it gives me a fatal error while installing GRUB and that's it.

I've also tried to get back into live Ubuntu and reinstalling GRUB from there (mounting the EFI partition in a temp dir). The intallation looks fine but alas, the machine can't find anything to boot when I reboot it.

What's going on?

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI mode? Post this: `sudo parted -l` What brand model system?

Comment: the laptop is a Gigabyte Aero 15x v7. Is it maybe that I can't create a second EFI partition on the system? I'm just trying not to lose any functionality in Windows 10 since I need it to work. I thought that removing the ssd with Win10 and installing Ubuntu in the other ssd would allow me to dual boot from the laptop boot menu. Reading more about UEFI and secure boot I don't think this is possible. Am I right?

Comment: You can have an ESP on every drive/device. I normally put an ESP on every drive and on larger flash drives. But Ubuntu's grub wants to install to first ESP. When you unplug Windows drive, is then the drive you are installing into seen as sda or first NVMe drive? Post partition info.

Comment: ```Model: SAMSUNG MZVKW512HMJP-00000 (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  460GB  460GB   primary   ntfs
 2      460GB   512GB  52.4GB  extended
 5      460GB   460GB  499MB   logical   fat32           boot, esp
 6      460GB   470GB  9999MB  logical   ext4
 7      470GB   506GB  36.0GB  logical   ext4
 8      506GB   512GB  5930MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)```

Comment: Is it the partition table that is msdos instead of gpt? That's my best guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I made it. Basically the disk I was trying to install Ubuntu on needed to be formatted completely so that Ubuntu could create a new partition table as gpt instead of msdos (the drive was used as storage for Win10). Once I did this I was able to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode dual boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you had left the SSD with Windows 10 in the system you would not have had any trouble at all. By removing that drive, you also removed the default EFI partition that was already on your system.
EFI is designed to be capable of installing multiple OS'es on one system across different media. The EFI partition is needed for that purpose and will hold the boot loaders for all the installed OS'es, including the tools needed for maintaining EFI itself and usually also holds a EFI boot menu to choose the desired OS should you not want to use GRUB or some other boot manager.
For a detailed description on how to install linux on a EFI computer check this page: http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/
This page also has links to detailed UEFI documentation.

Comment: Well after posting this I've learned about EFI. I didn't want to touch the Win EFI partition at all and actually it is possible to have different EFI partitions on different disks. That's actually how I'm using it right now. So your patronizing answer is quite irrelevant.